# how to do crud operations using springboot via models, services and controllers

Tags: mongodb, model-view-controller, crud

I am new to spring boot framework.According to the basic knowledge I have I know that spring boot is a framework which uses the MVC architecture. Can anyone provide me a coding example of how to use models, services repositories and service in this framework

Comment: It appears as though you've posted multiple answers containing code snippets which should really be part of your question. Questions and answers have an edit feature. Instead of posting answers to include these, you should [edit] your question instead. If you are being stopped from editing your question because it contains too much code, you should try to shorten it down to the shortest code necessary to reproduce your issue (This is what the community refers to as a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

first you have to connect with the database. Put the below code in the application.propperties class

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/test
```

Answer (score 0):

then your model class would look something like this

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Person {
@Id
String id;
String firstName;
String LastName;
int age;

public void Person(String fname,String lname,int age)
{
    this.firstName=fname;
    this.LastName=lname;
    this.age=age;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Person First Name: "+this.firstName+" "+this.LastName+"     
age:"+this.age;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be your repository interface

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;


@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person,String>
{
   public Person findByFirstName(String fname);
   public List<Person> findByAge(int age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be your service

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import com.example.demo.repository.PersonRepository;

@Service
public class PersonService 
{

 @Autowired
 private PersonRepository personRepository;

 //create operation
 public Person create(String fname,String lname,int age) 
 {
    return personRepository.save(new Person(fname,lname,age));
 }

 //retriew Operation
 public List<Person> getAll()
 {
    return personRepository.findAll();
 }

 public Person getByFirstName(String fname)
 {
    return personRepository.findByFirstName(fname);
 }

 //update operation
 public Person update(String fname,String lname,int age)
 {
    Person p = personRepository.findByFirstName(fname);
    p.setFirstName(fname);
    p.setLastName(lname);
    p.setAge(age);
    return personRepository.save(p);
    //personRepository.delete(p);
  }

 //delete
 public void deleteAll()
 {
    personRepository.deleteAll();
 }

 public void delete(String fname)
 {
    Person p  = personRepository.findByFirstName(fname);
    personRepository.delete(p);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the controller class

```
package Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import com.example.demo.service.PersonService;

@RestController
public class PersonController {

@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

@RequestMapping("/create")
public String create(@RequestParam String fname,@RequestParam String lname,@RequestParam int age)
{
    Person p = personService.create(fname, lname, age);
    return p.toString();
}

@RequestMapping("/get")
public Person getPerson(@RequestParam String fname)
{
    return personService.getByFirstName(fname);
}

@RequestMapping("/getAll")
public List<Person> getAll()
{
    return personService.getAll();
}

@RequestMapping("/update")
public Person update(@RequestParam String fname,@RequestParam String lname,@RequestParam int age)
{
    Person p = personService.update(fname, lname, age);
    return p;
}

@RequestMapping("/delete")
public void deleteByName(@RequestParam String fname)
{
    personService.delete(fname);
}

@RequestMapping("/deleteAll")
public void deleteAll()
{
    personService.deleteAll();
}


}
```

this is another example

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
public class CourseTotalController {

@Autowired
CourseTotalRepository repository;

@Autowired
SubjectRepository SubRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/total/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Courses calcTotal(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    float total = 0;

    Optional<Courses> opt =  repository.findById(id);
    Courses modifiedCourse = opt.get();
    String [] Subjects = opt.get().getSubjects();   

    for(int i=0;i< Subjects.length;i++) {
        Optional<Subject> SubjectOpt =  SubRepository.findById(Subjects[i]);
        total = total + SubjectOpt.get().getAmount();
    }
    modifiedCourse.setTotal(total);

    return modifiedCourse;
}
}
```